# Filling Gaps of Data SQL - Using Partition By or Left Outer Join on a Window

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Example of What I want]

I have been racking my brain on this for hours and am in need of some assistance. I have a a set of transactions that all must be added to a "Super Transaction".

So for example, one submission type requires 8 different "unique" transactions that are ID'd by their `BTT_id` so `BST_id` requires that there is a transaction of 1,2,3,4,5,7,9 in order for it to be a successful super transaction.

I need a way to group the transactions in a way that if there is a "gap" or a missing transaction, then it will fill the gap with a default transaction that I have setup.

I am trying to run a `Partition by` windowing function on the `BTT_id` so that it appears to have two `BTT_id`'s for each `Bsub_id` and then I can order them so that a "real" transaction always is first, then it's as simple as only selecting row 1 in my `Select` statement and if that transaction is missing then the only one left is the "default" transaction.

The problem is as shown in the table below, I don't know how to use a `Partition by` clause on an ID and still be able to have my "default transaction in the ranking. I wish I could send the code but the HIPAA laws do not let me copy and paste from my DEV Machine.

I made up some fake client_id's and encounters in that table in the picture to try to show what I am hoping to accomplish.

Thank you..

Hope you can shed some light of how I can accomplish what to me sounds like it should be something simple to do. Thanks

-Garen

Comment: Please provide some example data as reproducible DML/DDL. One method of doing this is:
`DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 NVARCHAR(10), Col3 DATE); INSERT INTO @Table (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (1, 'String', '2023-05-24'), (2, 'String2', '2023-05-25');`. Please also provide a desired output (preferably as a table).

Answer (score 0):

It's *very* unclear what you're trying to achieve because you only include the "expected" and not the original data. Also, using image instead of text data is not cool.

But if i understand you, you have some transactions which needs to be filled out with dummys per type if real tran is missing.
One way to do it is something like this i guess:

```sql
DECLARE @base TABLE (
    btt_id INT
,   btt_name varchar(30)
)

INSERT INTO @base (
    btt_id, btt_name
)
VALUES  (1, 'Header')
,   (2, 'Client demo')
,   (3, 'Client address')
,   (4, 'Client profile')
,   (5, 'Service ep')
,   (6, 'Program identification')
,   (7, 'Co-occurant')
--, (8, 'Fundin''')
,   (9, 'Substance use')

DECLARE @transactions TABLE (
    id int
,   btt_id int, btt_name varchar(30)
)

INSERT INTO @transactions 
    (
    id, btt_id, btt_name
)
VALUES  (1, 1, 'Header')
,   (1, 3, 'Client address')
,   (1, 6, 'Program identification')
,   (2, 1, 'Header')
,   (2, 2, 'Client demo')

SELECT  'before', *
FROM    @transactions
ORDER BY id, btt_id

INSERT INTO @transactions (
    id, btt_id, btt_name
)
SELECT  i.id, b.btt_id, b.btt_name
FROM    @base b
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT  DISTINCT id
    FROM    @transactions
    ) i
LEFT JOIN @transactions l
    ON  l.btt_id = b.btt_id
    AND l.id = i.id
WHERE   l.id IS NULL

SELECT  'after', *
FROM    @transactions
ORDER BY id, btt_id
```

I create some tables that contains all the transactions that needs to be created and some sample data.

Then it's pretty much a cross join between the IDs you want to work on together with list of needed transactions. This set is the left joined against your transaction table to see all the "holes", and then i populate the transaction table with the missing data.

It's not exactly your data, but hopefully you can apply the concept for your particular case